# How to find the directory where R is installed in OS X?

Tags: r, macos

Everyone, I am new to R. Please forgive me if this question is too simple. I searched online, and some say `R.home()` works. So, I did, and I got `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources`. Is this right? If so, then how to find that folder specified by this specific path ? Many thanks.

Comment: The `Library/` folder is hidden by default. Assuming you're on Mavericks, [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14330) will tell you how to access it.

Comment: <rant> I cannot figure out why Apple thought it was a good idea to hide most directories from the user.  That's one of the main reasons I'm staying w/ SnowLeopard as long as I can </rant> . But, back to the question at hand: why do you want to find the directory? Some `R` config files do *not* reside there (others do).

Comment: Thanks so much, guys. I red from a book that " the functions available to the user are stored in a disk called R_HOME/library (R_HOME is the directory where R is installed)."

Comment: @CarlWitthoft You can show hidden files on a Mac: http://ianlunn.co.uk/articles/quickly-showhide-hidden-files-mac-os-x-mavericks/ (on other versions of OS X you might need to write TRUE instead of YES)

Comment: @ExpectoPatronum Thanks -- yes, I know how to display hidden files, and to display the "dot-extensions."  My rant is that these things should *always* be visible to the user.  Just as  `~/Library` should always be visible (which it isn't by default in Yosemite).

Comment: `R.home()` works in R Studio. After running the command it returns `"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources"`. And if you are unable to run R from the terminal then you can add path variable using `export PATH="$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources"`. After that close the terminal and then run the `R`. Now it should run just fine.